Pointing flash at LCD television creates a weird diffraction effect
I was looking around my room for something with my phone’s flash on, and noticed a very unique pattern reflecting off of the television.
FYI. The flash is white.
Any idea why it diffracts like that?



Also why are the spectra on the left side inside of the triangle created from the reflected rays, but on the right its on the outside?
Also if I’m not mistaken I can see an interference pattern horizontally to the right.
Also, the pictures were heavily smoothed by my phone, if anyone has any clue how to turn that off so I can take photos that are not smoothed it would be great

https://jasmcole.com/2016/02/21/tv-diffraction/ Jason Cole made a post about this and I think there is no reason to replicate his work which is already extremely well explained in his website.

Perhaps there are repeating little structures with a shape like this:

The edge diffractions could in that case explain the six rays that we see. And if the pitch is in the order of 100$\mu$m, colored fringes in the order of 1 cm would be expected. But this is just a guess, you should take a microscope or magnifying glass and take a close up of the screen to see what is really visible in there!
